# Where are Lamport OTP used?

Tags: one-time-password

I understand that Lamport OTP uses hash chains to generate passwords. Is it practically feasible to use them?
Where are Lamport OTP being currently being used?

I read some online papers that state that Lamport OTPs are computationally intensive and hence other schemes are preferred over them. Is there any known service that uses this?(like banks OTPs)

Comment: I don't see a reason to ever use them over CTR mode based OTPs with when you want *short* OTPs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lampport OTP's doesn't require a shared secret, it is extremely feasible to use them, particularly where services which require successive authentication.

Assume the following

```
A = Hash(B)
B = Hash(C)
.
.
.
Y = Hash(Z)
```

The entire hash chain above will be generated at the client and will be stored. The exchanges between client and server will be as follows.

```
[Client] -----------A-----------> [Server] Stores A
[Client] -----------B-----------> [Server] Verifies if Hash(B) == A; If yes, authenticates and discard A and stores B. If No, authentication failure.
[Client] -----------C-----------> [Server] Verifies if Hash(C) == B; If yes, authenticates and discard B and stores C. If No, authentication failure.
```

And coming to your question, here is [an example](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078022/open-source-tools/lamport-s-one-time-password-algorithm--or--don-t-talk-to-complete-strangers--.html) on how Lamport OTPs are used for securing client service interactions.

Comment: What if an attacker intercepts the seed value, A? Or are we assuming the communication is over a secure channel?

Comment: @Rads A isn't the seed value. The seed here is Z. Attacker wouldn't be able to do anything even if he or she has A from the first transaction. Because for the attacker to successfully authenticate, he/she will have to get B from A. B = Hashinverse(A) . Since hash inverse is not mathematically feasible it is useless. Of course the protocol is still vulnerable to MITM kind of attacks but consider this strictly as an authenticationechanism

Comment: I read some online papers that state that Lamport OTPs are computationally intensive and hence other schemes are preferred over these. Is there any known service that uses this?(eg. banks OTPs)